# Regular expression to read last number in a line

Tags: regex

I have a file, lets say it contains many lines and the last line is something like "abc 231 axy 546 321365", how can we extract only the last number of last line i.e., 321365 using regular expression if its possible?

Comment: What about "abd  32.25"? Do you mean the last integer, or the last real number?

Comment: Also, if there is not a number at the end, what do you want? e.g. `stuff 3245 trailing text`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid the number is always gonna be integer, no decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex '(\d+)$'

it means: [(group of) 1 or more digits] followed by end of line

Comment: thats working. thanks. one more quick question. if there are multiple lines in a file and I want only the last number of last line. can we pick that up using regex?

Answer (score 1):

To get only the last number of the string, you should say you want characters **between 0 and 9**, in the **end** of the string.
Here is the regex for that:

```
[0-9]+$
```

**[0-9]** means you are searching a number between 0 and 9,

**+** means at least 1 recurrence

**$** means the end of the string